# Custom listener for stroke width

Tags: android, interface, width, listener, stroke

I have a custom View in which I am able to draw lines, I can also choose which width the lines are. I also have a statistic which is in another fragment in which I should show how much lines from which stroke are drawn.

So I want to create a custom listener which should react on diffrent stroke widths. Whenever the stroke changes the statistic should show the **fresh** count of the stroke which was choosen...

I tried it with an interface, but I really don't no how to advance. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of your code, I think you could try something like that:

//DrawerLines

```
public class DrawerLines extends View {

private int _countLines;
private LinesCounterListener _linesCounterListener;

public DrawerLines(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void addCountLinesListener(LinesCounterListener linesCounterListener) {
    _linesCounterListener = linesCounterListener;
}

private void drawLines() {
    //Draw your lines
    if(_linesCounterListener != null) _linesCounterListener.updateCountLines(_countLines);
}

}
```

//LinesCounterFragment

```
public class LinesCounterFragment extends Fragment implements LinesCounterListener{

private TextView textView;
private DrawerLines drawerLines;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lines_counter_fragment, container, false);
    textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    drawerLines = (DrawerLines) rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawerLines);
    drawerLines.addCountLinesListener(this);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void updateCountLines(int count) {
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
}
}
```

//LinesCounterListener

```
public interface LinesCounterListener {
    public void updateCountLines(int count);
}
```

Comment: `drawerLines = (DrawerLines) rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawerLines);` which id do you pick there?